# Array size not passing to function

Tags: c++, arrays, size

When passing an array to a function and using sizeof() in the fuction, it just returns the size of a single element (4). Is there a way to fix this? And I'm limited to only using arrays, not vectors/templates.

```
void arraysize(int arr[]){
    cout << sizeof(arr) << endl;
}

int main(){
    int a[15];
    arraysize(a);                  //4
    cout << sizeof(a) << endl;     //60
}
```

Output:

```
4
60
```

Comment: The issue is that the function signature is adjusted to `void arraysize(int* arr)`, so `arr` is really a pointer to `int`. There are plenty of questions on this topic on SO.

Comment: You cannot pass an array to a function in C++ directly.

Comment: @immibis Note that this is C++. You can't pass by value, but you can pass references/pointers to arrays.

Comment: @juachopanza Yes, but passing a reference/pointer to an array isn't passing the array.

Comment: @immibis Why not? One could argue passing by value isn't passing the array either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the array by reference to keep the size info:

```
void arraysize(int (&arr)[15]);
```

with template to auto deduce the size:

```
template <std::size_t N>
void arraysize(int (&arr)[N]);
```

So without template/STL, you have to pass the the size info in some way:

```
void arraysize(int *arr, std::size_t size);
```

or

```
void arraysize(int *arr, int* end);
```

Comment: I like this. But I guess he do not understand templates(yet).

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) [decay](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html).

Comment: Also adjustment. Array decay isn't the only thing going on in OP's code. There has to be a context that requires the array decay in the first place.

Comment: The context that requires array decay is the function call. See the first sentence of http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html#2-4

Comment: Only because the function takes a pointer, due to *adjustment*. If the function took something that didn't require a pointer to element of the array, there'd be no decay.